# Leaflet marker is not displaying

Tags: leaflet, cartography, markers

I am currently having slight problem on displaying marker in the leaflet. I have used the following codes on displaying marker and map, however the map is displaying flawlessly but the marker is invisible. I have also tried worldCopyJump true but no help.

```
var map = new L.Map('map', {
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 3,
    layers: [new    L.tileLayer('http://localhost:8080/1.0.0/osm/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',{tms: true})] 
});

var marker = L.marker([85.29009, 27.69545]).addTo(map);

//following also won't work
//var marker = L.marker([85.29009, 27.69545]);
//map.addLayer(marker);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks correct and the marker is visible, however, you will need to zoom out a little bit to see it since the marker you dropped is too close to the north pole (see image below):

[image]

I tested your on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vannizhang/h3o2q0p1/4/) and I am able to see the marker by changing the default zoom level from 3 to 0.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing it out. I just did not get that. BTW, I realized that the latlong that i supplied on the marker are altered i.e. I used latLng(Longitude, latititude) instead of latLng(latitude, longitude). And now, here it showing up in right location after altering the lat long value.  Thank you very much for your help!!!